# Prove that a surface of revolution is a 2dimension manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have a question about surface of revolution.

Prove that a surface of revolution is a 2dimension manifold. [image]

Answer (score 1):

hint: (u,v) are local coordinates.

Edit: the standard parametrization of a surface of revolution is $(f(v)\cos(u), f(v)\sin(u),g(v))$, where the given curve was $(f(v), g(v))$. Now, try to prove that locally (u,v) are coordinates (in few words, (u,v) give the local euclidean structure to the surface).
Hope this helps.

Comment: So? Please write more clear:/  @user67133

Comment: Unless there is a very good reason, we prefer not to arbitrarily delete good content: the answers could well help other users in the future.